# Codeigniter - Can I add my own column to the ci_sessions table in database?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I want to create a new column and call it "uid" because I want to access the session data from outside the `/applications` folder for a custom script that I am writing. So basically, I want to get the `uid` to get other user data from the user.

Is it okay to make my own column and add the uid as the user logs in? Is there a security problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: I didn't know that you write code :)

Comment: Yes, you can do this ... but keep in mind this column would contains duplicates (More than 1 session per user) And you cannot force the current implementation to fill that field for you, so you would have to insert the user-id after creating a session e.g: ->where('id', session_id())->update('sessions', ['uid' => $user_id]); or something like that.

Comment: Hey, can you please explain more on this? After creating a new column, I am not able to log in to the website. It displays a blank page.